# C# DataGridView to Excel File errors

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, datasource

I've coded this following a youtube tutorial, on the tutorial the DataSource is an AOD.NET Entity Data Model where I've used an Access Database instead. I've compiled the code but am getting various errors like

`The name 'productBindingSource' does not exist in the current context`
or
`The name 'DB' does not exist in the current context`
or
`The type or namespace name 'Product' could not be found`

I'm not sure if i've missed adding a reference or if these errors are due to the data source being different?

Visual Studio automatically added the `//TODO: This line of code etc...` and I changed it to how it's showing in the tutorial.

I'm hoping someone can help show me what i'm doing wrong?

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wGzK1vsqS8

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExportWebsiteData
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Product> list = ((DataParameter)e.Argument).ProductList;
            string filename = ((DataParameter)e.Argument).FileName;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;
            excel.Visible = false;
            int index = 1;
            int process = list.Count;
            //Add Column
            ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Item Number";
            ws.cells[1, 2] = "Model";
            ws.cells[1, 3] = "Manufacturer";
            ws.cells[1, 4] = "Category";
            ws.cells[1, 5] = "Subcategory";
            //
            foreach(Product p in list)
            {
                if (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / process);
                    ws.Cells[index, 1] = p.ItemNumber.ToString();
                    ws.Cells[index, 2] = p.Model.ToString();
                    ws.Cells[index, 3] = p.Manufacturer.ToString();
                    ws.Cells[index, 4] = p.Category.ToString();
                    ws.Cells[index, 5] = p.SubCategory.ToString();
                }
            }
            //Save file
            ws.SaveAs(filename, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookdefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, false, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            excel.Quit();
        }

        struct DataParameter
        {
            public List<Product> ProductList;
            public string FileName { get; set; }
        }

        DataParameter _inputParameter;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (this.inventoryTableAdapter.Fill(this._Wizard_Data_2016_10_17DataSet.Inventory); = new _Wizard_Data_2016_10_17DataSet())
            {
                productBindingSource.DataSource = DB.Products.ToList();
            }

            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the '_Wizard_Data_2016_10_17DataSet.Inventory' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            //this.inventoryTableAdapter.Fill(this._Wizard_Data_2016_10_17DataSet.Inventory);

        }

        private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            lblStatus.Text = string.Format("Processing...{0}", e.ProgressPercentage);
            progressBar.Update();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Error == null)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                lblStatus.Text = "Your data has been successfully exported.";
            }
        }

        private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
                return;
            using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls" })
            {
                if (sdf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    _inputParameter.FileName = sfd.FileName;
                    _inputParameter.ProductList = productBindingSource.DataSource as List<product>;
                    progressBar.Minimum = 0;
                    progressBar.Value = 0;
                    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(_inputParameter);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

John's answer did fix my errors but the data-grid is now being populated by the cs code instead of a database. I've made a video explaining the problem in more detail if anyone can let me know what they think is the problem.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1l5iw1j32a6oroj/C%23Excel.wmv?dl=0

Comment: Hello Alex, Others may not even look at this question since it has already been answered AND your question (connecting to an access db) is different from the original post. I will try and update my answer in a little while as there is more than one way to connect to your access database. You may consider posting another question for this focusing on the `Form1_Load` code, which is where this connection is taking place. If you wish we could set up a chat if it will help.

Comment: Hello John, A chat would be great how do we proceed?

Comment: Please give me a minute and I will try and initiate one if possible.

Comment: Hello Alex, I have found a solution to getting to the access file and not use the `Product` class.

Comment: Is it on stackoverflow?

Comment: No I adjusted the current code you have

Comment: In my original question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137249/discussion-between-johng-and-alex-p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the posted code there are several errors and typos. It appears there is some problem in the `Form1_Load` method that gets the data. To break this up and since it appears the data used is a List of `Product` objects, the code below uses a `List` of `Product` objects. The list is then populated with some test data. This test data will be used as a `DataSource` for the `DataGridView`. Once the data is in the `DataGridView` the export button will successfully export the data from the `DataGridView` to an Excel workbook.

Typos in the above posted code:

```
ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Item Number";
ws.cells[1, 2] = "Model";
```

Lower case “C” for cell columns 2,3,4,5 will throw a definition not found error.

```
ws.SaveAs(filename, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookdefault, ……);
```

Above this may depend on version, `xlWorkbookdefault` should have an uppercase “D”:

```
XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault
```

Last typo is in the `ShowDialog` for the `SaveFileDialog`

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog()
```

Then the next line tries to use:

```
sdf.ShowDialog()
```

The line above should be “sfd” not “sdf”.

Looking at the picture you have posted showing the errors and after watching the video you linked to, there are a couple of things the video may have missed. Starting from the top, it appears there is something called `Product` that is missing its definition. This looks like a class and from the code it appears the class has Item Number, Model, Manufacturer, Category and SubCategory. I am unsure if the video neglected this or `Product` is something else I am missing. In this case to fix this missing definition the code below made a `Product` class with the above properties.

```
public class Product {
  public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
  public string Model { get; set; }
  public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
  public string Category { get; set; }
  public string SubCategory { get; set; }

  public Product(string iNum, string model, string manuf, string cat, string subCat) {
    ItemNumber = iNum;
    Model = model;
    Manufacturer = manuf;
    Category = cat;
    SubCategory = subCat;
  }
```

The next 2 errors (XlFileFormat and XlSaveConflictResolution) are generated because you are missing a using statement in the code. This appears to be left out of the video. To fix these two errors, place the line below at the top of the file where the using statements are located.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

error: int: type used in a using statement… see below in form load.

The two errors `productBindingSource` does not exist. The video placed a `BackgroundWorker` on to the form but I did not see a `BindingSource` placed. To fix this… in the designer, select a `BindingSource` component from the tool box and drop it onto the form, then change its name to `productBindingSource`.

The “DB” error will be commented out to use the List of product objects. See below Form_Load.

“Thread” error indicates a missing using statement:  place the line below with the other using statements.

```
using System.Threading;
```

The “sdf” was covered above. The last error is from the line below:

```
productBindingSource.DataSource as List<product>;
```

`product` should have an upper case “P”: `List<Product>;`

With the above changes made, the only errors should be in the Form_Load method.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (this.inventoryTableAdapter.Fill(this._Wizard_Data_2016_10_17DataSet.Inventory); = new _Wizard_Data_2016_10_17DataSet())
  {
     productBindingSource.DataSource = DB.Products.ToList();
  }
}
```

The above line is malformed but appears to be trying to get a `DataSet`. I will leave this for your consideration later. Since the `productBindingSource` appears to be taking a List of Product objects, the code replaced this and created a List of Product objects for test data. The `Form_Load` method is changed to the code below which sets the `productBindingSource` to the list of test data, then this binding source is assigned as the `DataSource` for the `DataGridView`. This is missing in the video.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  List<Product> list = GetProductList();
  productBindingSource.DataSource = list;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = productBindingSource;
}
```

With the above changes the code exports as expected. Hope this helps.

```
private List<Product> GetProductList() {
  List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    products.Add(new Product(i.ToString(), "Model_" + i, "Manufacture_" + i, "Cat_" + i, "SubCat_" + i));
  }
  return products;
}
```

Edit update to get a table from the access DataBase without using a class

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

public Form2() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
  //List<Product> list = ((DataParameter)e.Argument).ProductList;
  System.Data.DataTable list = ((DataParameter)e.Argument).ProductList;
  string filename = ((DataParameter)e.Argument).FileName;
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
  Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
  Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;
  excel.Visible = false;
  int index = 1;
  //int process = list.Count;
  int process = list.Rows.Count;
  //Add Column
  ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Item Number";
  ws.Cells[1, 2] = "Model";
  ws.Cells[1, 3] = "Manufacturer";
  ws.Cells[1, 4] = "Category";
  ws.Cells[1, 5] = "Subcategory";
   foreach (DataRow dr in list.Rows) {
    if (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending) {
      backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / process);
      ws.Cells[index, 1] = dr.ItemArray[1].ToString();
      ws.Cells[index, 2] = dr.ItemArray[2].ToString();
      ws.Cells[index, 3] = dr.ItemArray[3].ToString();
      ws.Cells[index, 4] = dr.ItemArray[4].ToString();
      ws.Cells[index, 5] = dr.ItemArray[5].ToString();
    }
  }
  //Save file
  ws.SaveAs(filename, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, false, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
  excel.Quit();
}

struct DataParameter {
  public System.Data.DataTable ProductList;
  public string FileName { get; set; }
}

DataParameter _inputParameter;

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Test\Test3.accdb";
  using (OleDbConnection olcon = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)) {
    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter()) {

      string command = "SELECT * FROM [Products]";
      //cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";

      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, olcon);
      //Fill Gridview with Data from Access
      try {
        dt.Clear();
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        productBindingSource.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = productBindingSource;
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
      }
      finally {
        olcon.Close();
        var totalWidth = dataGridView1.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.None);
      }
    }
  }

}

 private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
  progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
  lblStatus.Text = string.Format("Processing...{0}", e.ProgressPercentage);
  progressBar.Update();
}

private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Error == null) {
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    lblStatus.Text = "Your data has been successfully exported.";
  }
}

private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
    return;
  using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls" }) {
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
      _inputParameter.FileName = sfd.FileName;
      //_inputParameter.ProductList = GetProductsList2();
      _inputParameter.ProductList = (System.Data.DataTable)productBindingSource.DataSource;
      progressBar.Minimum = 0;
      progressBar.Value = 0;
      backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(_inputParameter);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Highly appreciate this detailed answer it really helps in understanding whats going on and how to fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: thanks again for your answer I got all my errors fixed. Now the malformed `Connection String` for lack of a better word in my knowledge of C# I modified from what they show on the video to populate my `datagrid` with info from an `access database` than in the video they use a different `datasource` from the `northwinds DB`.

With these changes my application does run with no errors but populates the datagrid with data (I think that we hard-coded into the .cs file) instead of grabbing it from the access database?

Apologies if i'm mistaken some terminology i'm limited in C# knowledge

Comment: i've made a short video explaining a bit better what i'm trying to describe in my comment above if you have a few minutes anytime to take a look.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1l5iw1j32a6oroj/C%23Excel.wmv?dl=0
Much appreciated,
Alex